# Implement OAuth from server (Python) or from client (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, python, oauth

I would like to know which option (see title) is better, and why.  It seems there is a nice JavaScript OAuth product called

https://oauth.io/home

I am considering using it, but first I would like to know if there are other libraries that make it easy too.  And which may be best.  I certainly don't want to manually implement OAuth for all these websites (facebook, twitter, etc) separately.  Sounds complicated!